# How do I get drush to run remote drush not in a path?

Tags: drush

A remote server doesn't have drush, so I put it in my `~`.

Adding a `$PATH` works fine for myself being logged in, but since `ssh [command]` wont open a shell, `$PATH` is never picked up when I use `drush @remote-alias status`.

Answer (score 3):

The alias setting `%drush-script` is used to solve this.

```
$aliases['alias'] = [
  'path-aliases' => [
    '%drush-script' => '/home/[user]/bin/drush',
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

`ssh [command]` does source a bash resource file, but the rules for non-interactive shells are different than for interactive shells.  If you have only a .bashrc file, then it will be sourced for both interactive and non-interactive shells.  Most distros cause .bashrc to exit near the top of the file for non-interactive shells, so you have to set your $PATH at the top of the file for the changes to show up.

If you use .bash_profile or .profile or other bash resource files, the rules are more complicated.  See `man bash` for details.

Your workaround is also fine, of course.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have seen those early exits, that might explain what the issue was. I tried just adding the path to all the files I could think off, but I couldn't get it working. My interpretation of "Now that you mention it, I have seen those early exits, but if this is the case, then what should I make of "If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell." was then that no files at all got loaded. Perhaps that's not the case.